# How to post comments on websites without being traced back

Tags: web-browser, vpn, proxy, defense, user-tracking

Just trying to get some general sense about the security on internet now-a-days.

There are so many websites I go and comment on different things. If some comments are political and they don't like, I am afraid, they will trace me back.

So just wanted to know few basic things

1. Is it possible for any website (example-www.cnn.com) to trace me
   back based on my comment in their website. (If I have used a fake
   email id)
2. Is it possible that my ISP can trace me if they want?
3. Whats the best way I can browse and post my opinions fearlessly. I mean using proxy, vpn all those things.

If someone can put some light on these concerns, i would be very obliged.

Answer (score 2):

**How much a website knows**

Assuming you are browsing on a website without any protection, a website can know a great deal of things about a computer. Further, a great deal of this information is generally stored by the website in some sort of database. Often times, websites will store a great deal of information in order to remember some information about you in the event that you log on or register. I would be shocked if a message board did not at least tie your IP to your post in the event they want to ban it if a lot a spam comes from it. Your IP can be traced back to you by an ISP rather easily. It would be rather difficult, however, for CNN to know exactly who you are, though.

**How much and ISP knows**

Everything not sent encrypted on a network can be logged by an ISP if they wanted. Basically, we allow ISPs to be a man in the middle so we can do the whole internet thing. They basically, then, can know whatever they want about most internet traffic. And they of course know who you are.

**What to do**

I cannot tell you what the *best* method is simply because I doubt one exists. This question: [Whats the best way to make my internet traffic anonymous?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13416/whats-the-best-way-to-make-my-internet-traffic-anonymous) has some answers that you may want to look at. I personally prefer HTTPSeverywhere as a method of encrypting traffic to help against normal data interception. This, however, depends on the website being secure itself.  Note that proxies and VPNs trade in one level of trust for another. The website will know where the proxy or VPN is located. The proxy or VPN will know where you are located. You are not making yourself impossible to track, just harder. This question: [How does Google Maps know where I am, when I'm using a VPN?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/16253/how-does-google-maps-know-where-i-am-when-im-using-a-vpn) shows some instances where locations services were able to break through VPNs.

Comment: As an aside, as a very good highlighter to exactly how much a website can know about you, EFF also run https://panopticlick.eff.org/ which shows the uniqueness of your browser configuration when all plugins, versions and what-not are taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

Using a VPN service that has a trusted nature like [Private Internet Acces](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/), as they don't log user's activities ( well, many claim that but this VPN has gathered a good reviews from privacy advocates including [Rick Falkvinge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Falkvinge),[EFF](https://www.eff.org) etc with automated email masking services like [Blur from Abine Inc.](https://www.abine.com/index.html)
can help you a lot. You can't be anonymous using these but up to some extent you can avoid snooping. 
You can go with Tor but news about it are not healthy as recently a group of [MIT](https://newsoffice.mit.edu/2015/tor-vulnerability-0729) researchers pointed out that user's identity can be revealed with 88% accuracy. And many news have come across. So, good luck.